# jQuery Mobile close page dialog

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

How do I close the dialog page in jQuery Mobile?

In my particular case, I call another page as the page loading and then after the process is finished I want to ajax page loading closed and appeared again with a dialog page contains all the data received callback ajax.

My code :

```
$("#login").click(function(e){
LoadingPanel();
e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
        url:'http://www.myurl.com/soap/login.php',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        timeout: 15000,
        cache: false,
        data: dataString,
        success:function(response){

            //Dialog page closed here

            for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
                    var str,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7 = "";
                    str     = response[i].NE;
                    str2    = response[i].EMAIL;
                    str3    = response[i].TIPE;
                    str4    = response[i].NAMA;
                    str5    = response[i].TELP;
                    str6    = response[i].DN;
                    str7    = response[i].DESC_LOGIN;


                if(str=='-'){
                    alert('Data does not match')
                }else{
                var AllData = ""
                    AllData = 'Data1 : '+str+'\nData2 : '+str2+'\nData3 : '+str3+'\nData4 : '+str4+'\nData5 : '+str5
                    alert(AllData);
                    //How do I display this data into jquery mobile dialog?
                    } 
                }

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                if(thrownError==="timeout") {
                    alert("Cant connect");
                } else {
                    alert(t);
                }
            }
    });
  });
```

To the calling page loading :

```
function LoadingPanel(){
    $.mobile.changePage( "loading.html", { 
       role: "dialog" 
    });
}
```

How do I display this data into jquery mobile dialog when my data successfully accepted -> alert(AllData) ?

Comment: Use `$( ".selector" ).dialog( "close" );`

Comment: @Omar what selector ? i call a page (loading.html)

Comment: @BerthoJoris the selector can be any DOM element on the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you load `loading.html` using `$.mobile.changePage('loading.html', { role: 'dialog'});`, jQuery Mobile will give it a `data-role=dialog`. You can close it using the below.

```
$('[data-role=dialog]').dialog( "close" );
```

This will close the dialog, actually any open dialog, even if it doesn't have an `id`.

`.selector` means, `#id`, class `.class`, `data-role=something`...etc

Comment: is it working after jqm updated their dialog model ?, now any page can act as a dialog.

Comment: @IftikarUrrhmanKhan for 1.4 use `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "page id or URL")`, or `$,mobile.back()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also call the dialog's `close()` method to programmatically close dialogs.

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $("#bar").on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
        $("#btnClose").bind('click', function() {
            //alert('test');
            $("#bar").dialog('close');
        });

    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/pyCND/)**

Comment: What if the dialog was closed automatically?? 

Without the close button should be clicked.

In my case, the dialog will appear when the ajax process starts and will automatic closed when the ajax process is complete

Comment: @Mahesh My Dialog is on separate html page. This solution is not working in my case. So How can accomplish this in my case ????